# File uploading through curl in php

Tags: php, php-curl

I am trying to upload a file through curl on another server. I have created a script for this, but I am not able to get the `$_FILES` parameter. It's empty.

```
$request = curl_init('http://localhost/pushUploadedFile.php');
$file_path = $path.$name;
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
     $request,
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
     array(
      'file' => '@' . $file_path,
      'test' => 'rahul'
));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);exit();
```

pushUploadedFile.php:

```
print_r($_FILES['file']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of PHP are you using? In PHP 5.5 the curl option `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` was introduced which startet defaulting to `true` as of PHP 5.6.0. When it is `true` file uploads using `@/path/to/file` are disabled. So, if you are using PHP 5.6 or newer you have to set it to `false` to allow the upload:

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
```

But the `@/path/to/file` format for uploads is outdated and deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, you should use the [`CurlFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) class for this now:

```
$request = curl_init();
$file_path = $path.$name;
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/pushUploadedFile.php');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
     $request,
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
     array(
      'file' => new CurlFile( $file_path ),
      'test' => 'rahul'
));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('./sample.jpeg');
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $target_url ="http://www.localwork.com/pushUploadedFile.php";     
        $file_full_path = $path.$img_name;            
        $file_name_with_full_path = new CurlFile($file_full_path, 'image/png', $name);

        $post = array('path' => $path,'file_contents'=>$file_name_with_full_path);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
```